# Kibana: How I can find visualizations using an specific field or query?

Tags: kibana

We have tons of visualization in Kibana and I want to build a new one if does not exists. 
How I can search for those visualizations showing or using an specific field? 
Find them if the field is used on the query will be great as well.

**UPDATE**:

The search done by Kibana is only looking for matches at `title`and `description`.

Adding `visState` and `kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON` fields in the query will do the job.

Examples:

`https://kibana.server.com/es_admin/.kibana/visualization/_search?pretty&q=visState:*timing.started*`

`https://kibana.server.com/es_admin/.kibana/visualization/_search?pretty&q=kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON:*applicationName*`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally looks there is no way so I created a PR- support it with +1-
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/12164